# Electric Sheep does not start

Tags: 11.10, screensaver

Electric Sheep was working on my computer under Ubuntu 11.10 as a screen saver. Suddenly, here was a problem - `electricsheep` does not download any sheeps and nothing shows. Here is the output of `electricsheep --debug 1` :

```
=====================================
electric sheep v2.7b12
time start Thu Feb 23 14:14:13 2012
init_curl_cmd 0
curl_cmd = nice -n 10 curl --location --silent --show-error
server = v2d7c.sheepserver.net
play_counts init, thread=main
play counts: 59312:28
updating cache path=/home/uran777/.electricsheep/
thread main compute ranks
median rank undefined
begin delete cached 0
nothing cached
init_curl_cmd 1
query nice -n 10 curl --location --silent --show-error 'http://community.sheepserver.net/query.php?q=redir&u=uran777&p=D0D2B4063298BCBCB3B8CED231DB9617&v=LNX_2.7b12&i=348FCEE3056CD941'
updating cache path=/home/uran777/.electricsheep/
thread display compute ranks
median rank undefined
time display loop Thu Feb 23 14:14:13 2012
cleanup_and_exit 1
handle_sig_term waiter 0
cleanup.
writing play counts
handle_sig_term display 15
cleanup.
nplays = 0, nloopplays = 0, nrestarts = 0, ncached_sheep = 0
count standard deviation undefined
handle_sig_term main 15
writing play counts
cleanup.
handle_sig_term download 15
writing play counts
cleanup.
writing play counts
Завершено
```

Is it possible to somehow solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the first answer works, but you may want to change a little something in the xscreensaver settings. Once you have electricsheep installed and followed the instructions on the web page link, go into your xscreensaver settings, click on electricsheep as you 'saver of choice, then click on Settings -> Advanced.

Enter the line below as the executed command:

```
electricsheep --root 1 2> /dev/null
```

Electricsheep is known to display some error messages from StErr. They're not critical errors unless you see obvious performance issues when electricsheep is running. The above code routes the error messages to /dev/null, so you never see them displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there's a bunch of stuff which got changed it seems in terms of screensavers, I don't know how to resolve your problem but you may want to look at this guide and start from scratch:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/how-to-get-electric-sheep-to-work-with.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.